# How to disable accessibility automatically on Mac

Tags: macos

I am using accessibility function on Mac (10.9)and When I run the application I pop up a window to let use enable this function. But if I uninstall the application ,how come the Application is still in the enabled app list of accessibility?
And if I install the application and run again. How come the system is still asking me to enable this while the application is still enabled in the list?
I am using function like this

```
if (!AXAPIEnabled() || !AXIsProcessTrusted()) {
   do something;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your app signed?  I suspect that the signature is used to identify the authorized app.  If your code isn't signed, the OS may not realize that the previously-authorized app is the same as the reinstalled one.

Comment: @JWWalker, Yes, My app is signed with developer ID certificate. you mean only the authorized app can be shown in accessibility group? but what you said is a clue to me, originally my code is not signed and then I signed it sometime later. I am not sure whether it's caused by this...Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, if you authorize an unsigned app, the system will generate and store an *ad hoc* signature. If you later run an app you signed with your own certificate, it will be different from the system's point of view.

Comment: @KenThomases, I have verified all these on my machine, Thanks.